# ¿Cómo soluciono el no poder editar los márgenes de impresión en Access?

Tags: ms-access

Al tratar de editar los márgenes y escribir cualquier valor, no se mantiene los cambios y siempre se quedan estas medidas:
[image: Configuración que se mantiene]

Haciendo que las impresiones de los formularios salgan con más sespacio del lado derecho
[image: Cómo quedan los formularios]

Incluso, trate de modificar las opciones de Access y los cambios no se mantienen
[image: Opciones de Access]

Cabe mencionar que al elegir el margen Estrecho, éste no mantiene, pues al abrir de nuevo la pestaña de Márgenes se queda la configuración personalizada.

[image: Pestaña Márgenes]